# Detecting space in a file in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

Hi i was just wondering if anybody could help me i am reading characters from a file then inserting them into a map i have the code working i was just wondering how do i detect if a space is in the file cause i need to store the amount of times a space occurred in a file any help would be great thanks.

```
map<char, int> treeNodes; //character and the frequency
ifstream text("test.txt");

while(!text.eof())
{
    text >> characters;
    //getline(text,characters);
    cout << characters;
    if(treeNodes.count(characters) == 0)
    {
        if(isspace (characters))
        {
            cout << "space" << endl;
        }
        else
            treeNodes.insert(pair<char,int>(characters,1));
    }
    else
    {
        treeNodes[characters] += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use some periods and commas some time...

Comment: Spaces have a value of... wait for it... `' '`.

Comment: if this is homework, please tag it as such

Comment: @DmitryKachko: maybeitisinordertoanswerbackwithsomethingwhichalsoomitsallkindofspacestohelpbringhomethemessagethatpunctuationcasesetcactuallyhelpreadabilityalthoughitseemsthattheyoungonesseemtothinkthatitissomehowcooltogetbacktotherootsofwriting

Comment: If it not homework consider using using Boost's Regex library. I suspect you maybe recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatted input, i.e. when using the right shift `operator>>()` skips leading whitespace by default. You can turn this off using `std::noskipws` but depending on what sort of things you want to read it won't be a very happy experience. The best approach is probably using unformatted input, i.e. something like `std::getline()` and split the line on space within the program.

If you just want to count the number of times any particular character occurred, you probably want to use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` and just iterate over the content of the stream (this code also omits some other unnecessary clutter):

```
for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(text), end(); it != end; ++it) {
    ++treeNodes[*it];
}
```

BTW, you **never** want to use the result of `eof()` for something different than determining whether the last read failed because the stream has reached its end.

Comment: are the map values zero-initialized by default?

Comment: Depends on how you look at it: I'd say no. When a key isn't found in a map when using the subscript operator, a pair made up of the key and a default constucted value is inserted into the map. For built-in types this means they are zero initialized but more generally the value is default initialized.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just cast the char to an int and test if it is equal to the ascii value of  a space?

Comment: Do you know you can compare chars without casting it to int? -.-"

Comment: yeah you could but imho it would look kind of weird :-)

Comment: Wait, what? `if (a == ' ') {...}` looks weird? Let me show you your way... `if ((int)a == (int)' ') {...}`. I will let you decide which one looks weirder.